# configuring squid reverse proxy

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy

I want to configure reverse proxy by Squid. I edited squid.config but it doesn't work

```
#  TAG: http_access
http_access allow all
http_access allow localhost

http_access deny all


#  TAG: http_port
http_port 3128 defaultsite=220.69.***.*1 //my proxy server


#  TAG: cache_peer
chache_peer 220.69.***.*9 parent 80 0 no-query originserver
```

I have tested by chrome input url like this

```
 http://220.69.***.*1:3128
```

but I can just see ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.. What's the problem?